# How to create an Image button in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, imagebutton

How do you create a plain old image button in MVC 4 (Razor)?
I'm looking for something like this
[image]

Comment: that is done using css.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionTaken", "TestController"))   {
      <button name="button" value="ActionOne" class="button" style="width: 200px;">
         <img src=""/></button>
      <button name="button" class="button" style="width: 160px;" value="ActionTwo">
      <img src=""/></button>             }
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your razor view:

```
<input type="image" src="<image path here>" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
```